# how to transform OpaqueExtrinsic to get the variables within the transaciton?

Tags: transactions, extrinsic, subxt, block

I'm writing a custom `BlockImport` and I need to decode the transactions within the block,as we know a transaction is simply a pallet method call for example `store_value(value)`, but at the point where I'm verifying a block all I got is `OpaqueExtrinsic` which is the transaction encoded.

How can I take that extrinsic and retrieve the parameter `value` that was passed when the user called my pallet extrinsic `store_value(value)`?

Extra:
in the following code I'm just iterating over all the block extrinsics:

```
if let Some(block_extrinsics) = &block.body {
    let mut block_extrinsics = block_extrinsics.iter();
    block_extrinsics.next();
    for extrinsic in block_extrinsics {
             // what to do next ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substrate is build in the way that the runtime and the node are separate from each other. The node should not be able to interpret transaction as the runtime can upgrade at any point, which may also changes the transaction encoding. A proper solution here would be to define your own runtime api. Something like:

```
sp_api::decl_runtime_apis! {
    trait CheckExtrinsics<Block: BlockT> {
        fn contains_special_extrinsics(extrinsics: Vec<Block::Extrinsic>) -> bool;
    }
}
```

Then in your code you run this:

```
if let Some(block_extrinsics) = &block.body
{
    if client.runtime_api().contains_special_extrinsics(block_extrinsics.clone())? {
        // do something
    }
}
```

In your runtime you then need to implement the runtime api in whatever way you want.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but i want to know how to decode the opaque extrinsic to get the values within it

Comment: As I said, you should not do in your node code. What I have given you above, will give you the values within the extrinsic.

Comment: you said i need to implement the runtime api in whatever way i want, i dont know any way to decode the Extrinsics to retreive the argument `value` within an encoded `store_value(value)` extrinsic, what you have given me above is the proper place to decode it and i agree but it does not show how to actually decode it!

Comment: On the runtime side you will already get the decoded extrinsic. You will be able to inspect it there as you like. `Block::Extrinsic` is set to the concrete extrinsic type in your runtime.

Comment: i tried to follow your solution but the first thing that did not work is using Vec, since std is not allowed in the runtime i had to use a simple array of type `[<Block as BlockT>::Extrinsic;length]`, so i created a simple array that holds one `OpaqueExtrinsic` but that also for some reason  got me an error when trying to pass the argument to contains_special_extrinsics(my_array) which is `an argument of type &sp_api::BlockId<...::BlakeTwo256>, sp_runtime::OpaqueExtrinsic>> is missing`, even if make the function take one single OpaqueExtrinsic instead of an array the error still is the same

Comment: `Vec` is available. You can get it from `sp_std::vec::Vec`. The macro is generating you on the node side a function that takes a first "extra parameter". It expects the `at` parameter, aka the block in which context you want to execute this runtime call. In your case you need to pass `&BlockId::Hash(parent_hash)` as first parameter.

Comment: thank you so much sir, it is working great and i learned a lot